# Python - restructuring a list to only increase in increments of 1

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of numbers (in Python), some of which are repeated. The list looks like this:

Input

```
values = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]
```

When a number is not repeated, it will be equal to the starting number + the index of the new entry (example: 1833 = 1827 + 6).

Expected output

```
[1827,1827,1828,1828,1827,1827,1829]
```

So that repeating numbers do not change, but when a new number comes into play, I want it to be equal to the highest number in the list up until that point +1 (example: 1829 to become 1827 + 1 = 1828).

It would be worth noting that in this example, if the number 1833 were to appear again, it would need to be set to 1829.

So far this is my code:

```
contact_ids = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]
output = []
seen_ids = {}

for id in contact_ids:
    if id not in seen_ids:
        seen_ids[id] = id
        output.append(id)
    else:
        output.append(seen_ids[id])

print("CONTACT_ID")
for id in output:
    print(id)
```

Corresponding output:

```
CONTACT_ID
1827
1827
1829
1829
1827
1827
1833
```

Comment: if you want that, then start coding it

Comment: What have you donde so far? Could you add your code please?

Comment: Can you write out the rules in pseudocode please? I've created this three ways, and all ways I didn't get the same answer as you

Comment: the pseudocode would look like: (not very familiar with pseudocode so I apologise in advance for lack of convention)
-iterate through given list
-set first id to be the starting value
-if id on current iteration is unique up until now, change it (and all future instances of this id) to be equal to the last unique value + 1
- if id is not unique, set it to the value that the first instance of that id was set to

Answer (score 2):

The self-referential defaultdict trick in another (simpler & more efficient) way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]

d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d) + values[0])

[d[v] for v in values]
# [1827, 1827, 1828, 1828, 1827, 1827, 1829]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done elegantly with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a good `lambda`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]

d = defaultdict(lambda: max(list(d.values()) + [min(values) - 1]) + 1)
[d[value] for value in values]
```

```
[1827, 1827, 1828, 1828, 1827, 1827, 1829]
```

This works because we're binding the dictionary itself into the lambda it uses for setting the value of a missing key. We can `max` those values and figure out the right value.

We need to start the dictionary off with the lowest value in the `list` (alternatively you can start it off with the first value in the `list` with `values[0]`)

I profiled the solutions:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict


def max_defaultdict(values):
    # @swozny
    d = defaultdict(lambda: max(list(d.values()) + [min(values) - 1]) + 1)
    [d[value] for value in values]


def len_defaultdict(values):
    # @user2390182
    d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d) + values[0])
    [d[v] for v in values]


def dictionary_approach(contact_ids):
    # @John Coleman
    start = contact_ids[0]
    rank = 0
    ranks = {}
    for contact_id in contact_ids:
        if contact_id not in ranks:
            ranks[contact_id] = rank
            rank += 1

    output = [start + ranks[contact_id] for contact_id in contact_ids]


def setup(N):
    values = [1827]
    for _ in range(N - 1):
        next_value = values[-1] + random.randint(-2, 2)
        values.append(max(next_value, 1827))
    return [values]


from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison

approaches = [dictionary_approach, len_defaultdict, max_defaultdict]
run_performance_comparison(
    approaches, [10_000, 20_000, 30_000, 100_000, 200_000], setup=setup
)
```

[image]

The repeated `max` calls really put this solution far behind the dictionary solution. What's interesting is that the `len` based `defaultdict` beats even the dictionary.

Profiling Code

```
import timeit
from functools import partial

from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown(*data)


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               *,
                               setup=lambda N: [N],
                               teardown=lambda *N: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5,
                               title='Performance Comparison',
                               data_name='N',
                               yscale='log',
                               xscale='log'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}
    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            print(f'Running performance comparison for {data_name}={N}')
            for approach in approaches:
                function = partial(approach, *data)
                approach_time = min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=number_of_repetitions, number=1))
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale(yscale)
    plt.xscale(xscale)

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity because of the repeated `max` call (and the spurious list cast)..

Comment: Yep yep your solution is better :) I'm profiling the approaches as we're writing.

Comment: It's the best I could come up with and I got the self-referential trick right :) live and learn

Comment: Nice profiling code

Answer (score 1):

Define the rank of a contact id to be its index in the list of contact ids with duplicates removed. These are the offsets from the start in the intended output. They can be obtained in various ways. The following code does so using a dictionary, which is then used in a list comprehension to get the final output:

```
contact_ids = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]
start = contact_ids[0]
rank = 0
ranks = {}
for contact_id in contact_ids:
  if contact_id not in ranks:
    ranks[contact_id] = rank
    rank += 1

output = [start + ranks[contact_id] for contact_id in contact_ids]
print(output)
#[1827, 1827, 1828, 1828, 1827, 1827, 1829]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement that non-repeated numbers can be identified as being equal to their offset from the first one, you could can determine where the +1 increment should occur.  Then use `itertools.accumulate` to compute the total increment to apply to each position (from the base) and replace the larger values with it:

```
from itertools import accumulate

values = [1827, 1827, 1829, 1829, 1827, 1827, 1833]

inc      = accumulate( p if p == values[0] else p == n
                       for p,n in enumerate(values,values[0]))
*output, = map(min, zip(values,inc)) 

print(output)
[1827, 1827, 1828, 1828, 1827, 1827, 1829]
```